# MySQL statement to use group_concat in Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy some data from many rows to one. When I use Select everything shows as I want to but I can't convert it to Update query.
Please help me to find problem
The select and update are:

```
SELECT CONCAT( P.POST_CONTENT, GROUP_CONCAT(M.meta_value ORDER BY M.meta_id SEPARATOR 'CHAR(10)'))
FROM posts P
INNER JOIN postmeta M ON P.ID=M.post_id
WHERE M.meta_key = 'wpcf-obrazek'
GROUP BY P.ID
```

and

```
    UPDATE P, M
    SET P.post_excerpt = CONCAT( P.POST_CONTENT, GROUP_CONCAT(M.meta_value ORDER BY M.meta_id SEPARATOR 'CHAR(10)'))
    FROM posts P
    INNER JOIN postmeta M ON P.ID=M.post_id
    WHERE M.meta_key = 'wpcf-obrazek'
    GROUP BY P.ID
```

Error is:

```
#1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'FROM posts P
    INNER JOIN postmeta M ON P.ID=M.post_id
    WHERE M.meta_key ' w linii 3
```

Comment: This seems like a fundamentally poor idea to me. Are you sure that this is what you want to do?

Comment: Your syntax has nothing to do with MySQL.  What you want to do is a bad idea.  If you really want help with it, you should provide sample data and desired results.  But storing comma delimited values is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I posted another question that is my main problem. Here is my way to solve it. So I want to do this in few steps. Group all links in excerpt field and then copy excerpt to content

Answer (score 1):

Update should work if you join derived table with pre-processed data, please try:

```
UPDATE P
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT P.ID, CONCAT( P.POST_CONTENT, GROUP_CONCAT(M.meta_value ORDER BY M.meta_id SEPARATOR 'CHAR(10)')) AS data
             FROM posts P
               INNER JOIN postmeta M ON P.ID=M.post_id
             WHERE M.meta_key = 'wpcf-obrazek'
             GROUP BY P.ID
           ) AS excerpt_data ON P.ID = excerpt_data.ID
SET P.post_excerpt = excerpt_data.data;
```